# Monokai Pro Stylesheet

Tags: front-end, stylesheet

I am searching for a Monokai or Monokai Pro Stylesheet for Mathematica. Any idea of where I could find it or how I could easily import it from [Monokai Website](https://monokai.pro)?

Comment: If all you need is the CSS/styling, there are a bunch of CSS -> styles converters out there and then you can use these styles to make a custom stylesheet but I don't know of a pre-built stylesheet for it

Comment: I see. It would be nice if there was something directly available...

Comment: You could try to get some kind soul to scrape the CSS if you gave them something to pull the CSS from or could try to get WRI to help you out